Android Gradle taking More time in Build, Sync, and Change **Build variants**
In Android Studio, I recently updated Gradle to the current version, com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2. After the update, I am facing issues with longer sync times, delays when changing build variants, and increased time to generate APKs.
Currently i am using Android Studio Version: Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2.
App Gradle Dependency
` dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:8.3.37'

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.20"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.51'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.9.20"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'


        // r8 version
        //classpath("com.android.tools:r8:8.2.16-dev")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }`

Can anyone please help me understand what I might be doing wrong?
Thank you :)

Maybe you need to clear the Android Studio cache or you can use kapt/ksp to build more correctly if the project is large (this is if you are using kotlin) or similar if you are using Java.

Yes, my Project is large and i am using kotlin.

Already used kapt

How would kapt/ksp help "build more correctly"?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
